# What restrictions are there on the Facebook Social Plugin integration?

Tags: facebook, xaml, webview

I'm using the Page plugin feature in order to generate a rendered facebook events feed for a XAML application I'm working on.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

On the page, it gives you the option to put in a facebook link, and it will then render a timeline or events page in which you can grab HTML code from. I am taking the Iframe code and harvesting the URL, then having it render within a webview in XAML. The issue I am running into is that facebook won't render the page I need. This prevents me from getting the URL out of the Iframe.

Does anyone know what sort of restrictions facebook places on rendering page plugins?

Comment: What do you mean, you’re “harvesting the URL”?

Comment: Well, what that means is there is an Iframe embed link, and I shaved off the embed code and took or harvested the actual url from the page.

Comment: I also resolved the issue, Facebook won't allow you to embed a page with age restrictions on it. In other words, it will not render an age restricted page. However, I used wallflux RSS feed as a work around and embedded it anyways.

This resolved my issue.